# List processes associated with shared memory

Tags: process, ipc

When I run `ipcs -m` I get below info

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key     shmid      owner  perms  bytes   nattch status
0x00000 38699014   user   700    8125440 2      dest
0x00072 2064391    root   444    1       0
0x00000 38830088   user   700    299112  2      dest
0x00000 38862857   user   700    181720  2      dest
0x00000 38895626   user   700    244776  2      dest
0x00000 38928395   user   700    156816  2      dest
```

What I want is to get the processes(id) which use these shared memory. How do I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipcs -m -p` shows the shmid **and** the PID of the process that created it (the "cpid").

It also shows a "last operator" or "lpid" - I don't know what that is (the man page doesn't say so I'd having to dig deeper into the docs or source code to find out, and that's crazy talk!).

For example, on one of my systems (which happens to be running postgres and apache, amongst other things):

```
$ ipcs -m -p

------ Shared Memory Creator/Last-op PIDs --------
shmid      owner      cpid       lpid      
36         postgres   3155864    2367086   
38         root       14452      2362481
```

(apache, pid 14452, is shown with owner root.  It gets started as root, but changes to `www-data` when it pre-forks other processes).

We can use `awk` to extract the creator PID, and pipe that into `xargs -n 1 pstree -p` to show the tree of PIDs beneath those PIDs.

NOTE: `pstree` only takes a maximum of one PID argument at a time, so we have to use `xargs -n 1` to run `pstree` once per pid.

For example (using `pstree -A` for ASCII output. It'll probably look slightly prettier on your terminal without `-A`, using the default line-drawing characters):

```
$ ipcs -m -p | awk '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $3}' | xargs -n 1  pstree  -A -p
postgres(3155864)-+-postgres(1610942)
                  |-postgres(1620056)
                  |-postgres(1761109)
                  |-postgres(1831225)
                  |-postgres(1931537)
                  |-postgres(2123512)
                  |-postgres(2284745)
                  |-postgres(2386392)
                  |-postgres(3155867)
                  |-postgres(3155868)
                  |-postgres(3155869)
                  |-postgres(3155870)
                  |-postgres(3155871)
                  |-postgres(3155872)
                  `-postgres(3159321)
apache2(14452)-+-apache2(141263)
               |-apache2(762459)
               |-apache2(856005)
               |-apache2(856006)
               |-apache2(856008)
               |-apache2(856009)
               |-apache2(856010)
               |-apache2(856438)
               |-apache2(1369957)
               |-apache2(1777646)
               |-apache2(1887781)
               `-apache2(3746760)
```

If required, this can be post-processed (with awk or whatever) to extract only the PIDs from within the parentheses.

BTW, `pstree` has various other useful options (including `-u` to show uid transitions, and `-a` to show the full command line) to change what it outputs and how it formats it.

If you need to show the pstree for both the cpids and the lpids, use something like:

```
$ ipcs -m -p | awk '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {printf "%s\n%s\n", $3, $4}' | xargs -n 1 pstree -p
```

Comment: I tried your command, I got the relevant info under lpid header, not cpid :)

Comment: I got no output at all using $4 (lpid).  I guess your process tree depth must be greater than mine, or the PIDs are longer-lived, or something.  Did you find out what lpid is?

Comment: For me lpid is the process which is creating shmids. I created two processes one creates sharedmem and sends data and one receives data, the former is reported under lpid. I ran both processes for atleast 1 min so that reporting can be seen.

Comment: I was able to get the processes associated with the sharedmem id by using lsof | grep sharedmem id. Advantage of this is it lists out all processes which use the sharedmem id. Both creator and user processes.

Comment: yep, lsof is useful.  The trouble with `lsof` is that piping it into `grep` is slow...if you know the PID already, it's fast, but it's extremely slow if you're using it to find a PID.